# Как в opengl изменить направления осей?

Tags: c++, opengl

В opengl изначально y направлена вверх, x вправо, z в глубину. Как изменить направления осей так, чтобы z встало на место y. Мне нужно z направить вверх, а  y в глубину

Comment: Версия какая?) В 2.х - легко, glRotatef(a,x,y,z) -поворот на угол a в плоскостях x /y / z

Comment: Ну так перед рисованием поменять местами координаты, чтобы было как вы хотите?

Comment: если я правильно понимаю желание, то одними поворотами этого не достичь. Автор вопроса явно хочет систему координат DirectX, немного повернутую. Но хочется узнать, какую задачу решает автор.

Comment: Ну, изначально у openGL ось Z направлена от камеры. А хотелось бы сделать так, как в 3d редакторах, где ось Z направлена вверх. Opengl 4-й версии.

Comment: Это Ваше видение решения. Не меняйте, просто рисуйте так как Вам нужно